# Why won't compass connect?

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I am trying to make a connection with mongoDB compass with one of my clusters on atlas. I have whitelisted the IP address, and temporarily disabled my firewall, so I can't think of any other reasons why it wouldn't work. Also I know when you have copied the connection string and then open compass it normally detects it, but it won't detect it when I open compass.

Comment: Do you login on Mongo Atlas page and copy connection `url` from `connection` options?

Comment: I get the url from where it says "Copy the connection string below, and open Compass"

Comment: Okey, then make sure that your server is already online. The DBA (root) account for your database is created. Yes, `readWriteAnyDatabase` Then check (*I'm 99% sure that it's the source of the problem*) that your **auth_db** is correct (as for now it's `test`). Also, I recommend you to fill connection string separately, instead of using connection `uri`.

Comment: The correct `uri` string should starts with this:
`mongodb+srv://{login}:{password}@{hostname}/{auth_db}` And, as I saw, you are using `<>` in your password on both sides, which is wrong.

Comment: AlexZeDim yeah it was the <> that messed it up haha, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the <>, thanks AlexZeDim